# Is there a syntax that allows Mathematica to solve integral equations?

Tags: integral-equations

Is there syntax that causes Mathematica solve integral equations like the one below (I know that I can transform it to a differential equation. However, I would like to know if Mathematica solves equations in integral form.)?

$$
\int_{r_0}^{x} f(z) dz = \frac{kf(x)-L}{a}
$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [the documentation of `DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html#693507327) (emphasis mine):

> `DSolve` can solve ordinary differential equations (ODEs), partial differential equations (PDEs), differential algebraic equations (DAEs), delay differential equations (DDEs), ***integral equations***, integro-differential equations, and hybrid differential equations.

So you can just pass the equation to [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html), as you would with a differential equation:

```
DSolve[Integrate[f[z], {z, r0, x}] == (k f[x] - L)/a, f[x], x]
(* {{f[x] -> (E^((a (-r0 + x))/k) L)/k}} *)
```